# "Deine Fotos" gegen "Fotos von dir"

Tags: sentence-structure, possessive-pronoun

Bekanntlich benennt ein berühmtes soziales Netzwerk (meinem ersten Endruck nach dooferweise) zwei unterschiedliche Bilderordner mit den folgenden Namen: **deine Fotos** und **Fotos von dir**. Kann man tatsächlich den Unterschied zwischen denen schlussfolgern, wenn man nicht wüsste, worum es geht? Also, wenn die keine Bilder wären, sondern andere Objekte (sagen wir mal *X*), wäre ein Unterschied zwischen *deine X* und *X von dir* wirklich wahrzunehmen?

Comment: Die Frage kann nicht sinnvoll beantwortet werden. Selbstverständlich besteht ein grammatikalischer Unterschied zwischen beiden Formulierungen, der auch einen unterschiedlichen Bedeutungsgehalt nach sich zieht. Für eine allgemeine Aussage über die deutsche Sprache ist das aber keine taugliche Basis - eher als Illustration des unkritisch-falschen Gebrauchs der Präposition „von“ und der Schlampigkeit mancher Übersetzungen technikbezogener Texte aus dem Englischen.

Comment: *Du auf Fotos* would be better than ambiguous *Fotos von dir*, but in combination with *deine Fotos* the latter is disambiguated by context fairly well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wenn man beide Beschreibungen sieht, dann ist es durchaus möglich, sie zu differenzieren:

- "Deine Fotos": Die Fotos, die du selber aufgenommen (und hochgeladen) hast.
- "Fotos von dir": Die Fotos, die dich abbilden

Allerdings fällt die Unterscheidung meiner Meinung nach nicht ganz einfach aus, wenn man die Beschreibungen nur einzeln sieht:

- "Deine Fotos" bedeutet dasselbe wie oben beschrieben.
- "Fotos von dir" kann beides bedeuten. Wenn ich allerdings "Die Fotografien von dir sind sehr gelungen." hören würde, dann würde ich eher zu der Bedeutung tendieren, die die Fotos als Besitz interpretiert (= "Deine Fotos").

Des Weiteren passt der Begriff "Deine Fotos" besser in die Reihe der typischen Bezeichnungen sozialer Plattformen: deine Chronik, dein Profil, dein Status etc. Wenn dies konsistent auf einer Plattform umgesetzt ist, dann ist "Deine Fotos" auch ein ziemlich klarer Begriff.

---

Eine allgemeine Aussage ist nicht immer möglich, aber Folgendes gilt in meinen Augen für viele Anwendungsfälle:

- "dein X": X gehört dir, du bist der Eigentümer
- "X von dir": X gehört dir, aber der Besitz ist nicht unbedingt bei dir oder du steht in einem anderen Zusammenhang ("Fotos von dir" = "Fotos, die dich zeigen") zu X

Ein Beispiel:

- "Dein Computer": Der Computer, den du besitzt.
- "Der Computer von dir": Der Computer, den du mir zusammengebaut und geschenkt hast.

Answer (score 4):

Both "deine Fotos" and "Fotos von dir" are ambiguous, but "deine Fotos" is more likely to mean "photos that you made or own", and "Fotos von dir" is more likely to mean "photos having you as the subject", less likely "photos that I received from you", and the meaning "photos that you own" is possible, but bad German.

In the combination, two folders with different titles, the meaning is quite unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

"Deine Fotos" means photos uploaded by you. "Fotos von dir" means photos with you being on the picture.

Comment: I don't agree, "Fotos von dir" is ambiguous. It can have both meanings.

Comment: Both are a little ambiguous, but normally "Deine Fotos" is more used for possession while "Fotos von dir" can be interpreted both ways, but when put across "Deine Fotos" it should be obvious that it refers to photos with you in it.

Answer (score 0):

It can, but in this case, i.e. when we have this particular pairing, the other explanation if much likelier.