# „Im Haus von Marie“ aber „In Maries Haus“?

Tags: genitive

Ich habe diese Formulierung gelesen, und bin nicht sicher, wann sie angewandt wird. Mir ist nicht klar, warum aus „im“ oder „in dem“ in einem Fall „in“ wird.

> In dem Haus von Marie

das ist verständlich.

> Im Haus von Marie

das ist das Gleiche, nur verkürzt?

> In Maries Haus

ist das überhaupt richtig? Ich glaube, ich habe es in einer FAZ oder SZ gelesen, also gehe ich davon aus. Ist das auch wieder das Gleiche?

Wie heißt diese Regel, wo kann man das nachlesen? Ich finde es sehr schwierig, gute Stichworte für die Suche in dem Fall zu finden.

Comment: No, my question is not about the „von“ part, but the „in / im“ part. Do you think I should specify this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing the genitive with a "von" construction](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15141/replacing-the-genitive-with-a-von-construction)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich We already had this dupe proposal. That's why the OP responded in their 1st comment. They want to know what's the difference of _"Im Haus von Marie"_ and _"In Maries Haus"_ and if there's a rule for the 2nd one using _in_. There's no suitable explanation of this form in the dupe.

Comment: Note that the linked question is in English, yet the question is in German.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> in dem Haus von Marie

bedeutet dasselbe wie

> im Haus von Marie

*Im* ist eine **Verschmelzung** von *in* und *dem*. In diesem Beispiel würde man eher die zweite Form (mit *im*) sagen.

Im folgenden Beispiel ist der Gebrauch der Präposition *in* ohne einen Artikel richtig:

> in Maries Haus

Weder *in dem* noch *im* sind möglich. *Marie* ist ein Eigenname, der als [Attribut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribut_(Grammatik)) zu *Haus* fungiert. Daher steht der Name im Genitiv. Ein Eigenname als Genitivattribut kann vor das Substantiv, das er näher bestimmt, gestellt werden. In diesem Fall wird das Substantiv [definit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitheit_(Linguistik)). Der Eigenname fungiert hier wie ein bestimmter Artikel. Daher wäre der Artikel *dem* redundant und ist daher nicht zulässig. Man vergleiche mit der Situation, wenn der Eigenname als Attribut hinter das Substantiv gestellt wird. Dann legt der Eigenname die Definitheit des Substantivs nicht fest und ein Artikel ist erforderlich. Zwischen bestimmtem und unbestimmtem Artikel kann gewählt werden.

> in einem Haus Maries
> in dem Haus Maries

Das letzte Beispiel ist bedeutungsgleich mit

> in Maries Haus

---

(Ergänzung:) Es können – fast ausnahmslos – nur Eigennamen als Genitivattribut ohne Artikel vorangestellt werden. Mit anderen Substantiven ist das in der Regel nicht möglich. (Ein Beispiel für eine Ausnahme ist: *Schlafes Bruder* = *der Bruder des Schlafs*)

Des Weiteren kann so nicht mit allen Eigennamen verfahren werden, sondern nur mit jenen, die ohne Artikel stehen können (z.B. Vor- oder Nachnamen). Eine Voranstellung von Eigennamen mit obligatorischem Artikel bei Weglassung des Artikels ist ungrammatisch:

> * Atlantiks Inseln
> * in Atlantiks Bann

Comment: Danke! Ist das nur mit Eigennamen so? Wie ist es mit z.B. „Im Tal des Schmerzes“ — „In Schmerzes Tal“?

Comment: @ploen2018 "In Schmerzes Tal" würde man in Gedichten und Lyrik erwarten, dort wird es als Stilmittel durchaus auch benutzt. Im Alltag wirkt dies allerdings sehr prätentiös.

Comment: @ploen2018, it would be „in *des* Schmerzes Tal“, and it is the less common word oder in this case.

Answer (score 3):

> > In Maries Haus
>
> ist das überhaupt richtig?

Ja.

> Ist das auch wieder das Gleiche?

Semantisch ja.

Der Genitiv wird hier verwendet um auszudrücken, das es sich um einen spezifischen Ort handelt, der einer bestimmten Person zugeordnet wird.

> *Wo?*
> In einem Haus (*unspezifisch*)
> *In wessen Haus?*
> In Maries Haus
>
> *oder (s. [Replacing the genitive with a "von" construction](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15141/replacing-the-genitive-with-a-von-construction) in Englisch)*
> In dem Haus von Marie
> *oder*
> Im Haus von Marie

---

> Wie heißt diese Regel, wo kann man das nachlesen? Ich finde es sehr schwierig, gute Stichworte für die Suche in dem Fall zu finden.

Ich kann nicht sagen ob es dafür eine eigens benannte Regel gibt. Wenn ja dann kenne ich den Namen nicht (aber ich war noch nie gut in Grammatik).

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung, ich habe dennoch die andere als richtig markiert, weil sie mehr ins Detail geht. Und ich verstehe nicht ganz, warum bei Ihnen „In dem Haus von Marie“ doppelt ist, ein Tippfehler?

Comment: @ploen2018 Passt schon. Ein Tippfehler, ja.