# "Änderungen an D" vs "Änderungen in D" vs "Änderungen + G"

Tags: difference, preposition

Ich habe bemerkt, dass wenn es um Änderungen geht, immer die Preposition "an" verwendet wird.
Für mich klingen alle diesen Variante richtig mit "in" und mit "an" (oder sogar Genitive?):

1. Seitdem wurde (hat sich) im Framework nichts geändert.
2. Seitdem wurde (hat sich) am Framework nichts geändert.
3. Änderungen des Frameworks...

Stimmt das?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es kann sein, dass sich hier technischer Software-Speak und deutsche Sprache etwas auseinander-dividiert haben.

Änderungen „an“ einem Stück Software umfassen gewöhnlich sowohl das Interface als auch Interna. Änderungen „in“ der Software können u.U. rein intern sein.

Nimmt man ein anderes Beispiel, kommt man der Sache schon etwas näher:

> **In** Deutschland haben in den letzten Jahren große Änderungen stattgefunden

Vs.

> **an** Deutschland sind in den letzten Jahren erhebliche Änderungen vorgenommen worden

Bei diesen Beispielen wird klar, dass Änderungen „in“ etwas von innen heraus stattfinden, während Änderungen „an“ etwas von außen bzw. von einer überschaubaren Gruppe von innen verursacht wurden.

Auch „stattfinden“ bzw. „vornehmen“ sind zwischen den beiden Beispielen nicht austauschbar. “In” lässt den Verursacher vollkommen außer acht, während „an“ ihn geradezu hervorhebt.

Bei Software, wo eigentlich klar ist, dass nur die Entwickler Änderungen vornehmen können, sind beide Ausdrücke im wesentlichen allerdings gleichwertig.

Der Genitiv hat in den meisten Anwendungen den Nachteil, dass er *Aktor* und  *Objekt* nicht klar auseinanderhalten und deswegen mißverständlich sein kann (es gibt sowohl einen *genitivus objectivus* als einen *genitivus subjectivus*):

> Die Beachtung des Gesetzes

und

> Der Rat des Freundes

stellen zwei grundsätzlich unterschiedliche Verwendungen dar (der Freund ist das Subjekt der Handlung, das Gesetz das Objekt), die beide durch den Genitiv ausgedrückt werden.

> Die Änderungen des Frameworks

könnten also rein theoretisch Änderungen sein, die das Framework selbst vornimmt (z.B. an einer Datenbank), als auch Änderungen, die am Framework durchgeführt wurden (von einem Entwickler). Im Gegensatz dazu stellen die Konstruktionen mit Präposition ganz klar das Framework in die Objektrolle.

Comment: Aber mit (von + D) wird es ganz klar wer Subjekt ist? Ich wollte schon seit langen diesbezüglich eine Frage posten. Eventuell gestalte ich es al s eine separate Frage.

Comment: Es gibt schon ähnliches aber für die Fotos ist es ein spezieller Fall meiner Meinung nach https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13519/deine-fotos-gegen-fotos-von-dir

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde tatsächlich zu den Varianten 2 und 3 (*seitdem gab es keine Änderungen des Frameworks*) tendieren.

*Im* klingt hier seltsam. Ich würde das maximal dann verwenden, wenn ich ausdrücken wollte, dass es auch intern keine Änderungen gab, nicht nur an den Schnittstellen des Frameworks.

*In* würde ich beispielsweise hier verwenden:

> Es hat sich in unserer Beziehung nichts geändert

Das würde für mich bedeuten: wir haben immer noch eine Beziehung, denselben Beziehungsstatus und auch sonstige beziehungsrelevante Parameter sind dieselben.

> Es hat sich an unserer Beziehung nichts geändert

hätte für mich eher die Bedeutung, dass der nach außen sichtbare Beziehungsstatus eine Änderung erfahren hat.

Aber vermutlich sind das Spitzfindigkeiten, über die man trefflich streiten kann. Normalerweise würde ich *ändern* mit der Präposition *an* oder *Änderung + G* verwenden.